# How to replace sting with punctuation and convert?

Tags: sql, string, replace

I need to replace a phone string with punctuation inside and then convert it to int value.
I try to perform this query but i get all null because of the use of 'try_convert'.

Select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ',''), '0',''), '.', '') as phone, TRY_CONVERT (int, phone)
From sales. Customers

Comment: What RDBMS are you using. Can you share sample data where all this nested replaces are failing to convert? This feels like a more appropriate job for regular expression functions, but not knowing what platform you are using, those may or may not be available.

Comment: We don't know your DBMS yet, but in SQL it is generally not possible to use an alias in the same select clause where you define it.

Comment: You're naming an alias the same as the original column, so for one, how do you think `try_convert` *knows* which one you mean? Additionally, referring to an alias in the same `select` within which it's definied is (generally) not allowed, but why don't you just wrap `try_convert` around your `replace`?

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this? A phone number is not a number, you'll loose characters which will render the remaining information meaningless

Comment: I using ssms, I change the name of the alias and it still show the convert as a null value.

Comment: And this is the task that i got.
''The IT department would like to convert all the information about phone numbers in the
Sales.Customers table to integer values. The IT staff indicated that all hyphens, parentheses, and
spaces have to be removed before the conversion to an integer data type.
2. Write a SELECT statement to implement the requirement of the IT department. Replace all the
specified characters in the phone column of the Sales.Customers table, and then convert the column
from the nvarchar datatype to the int datatype''

Comment: I want to understand the way to the answer using REPLACE and TRY_CONVERT.
I

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function to strip all non-numeric characters from your input string.
Here's a variation I use.

```
CREATE FUNCTION usf_StripNonNumeric
(
    @Input varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r    VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
            ,@len INT
            ,@c   CHAR(1)
            ,@x   INT          = 0;

    SELECT @len  = LEN(@Input);

    WHILE @x <= @len
    BEGIN
        SELECT @c  = SUBSTRING(@Input, @x, 1);

        IF ISNUMERIC(@c) = 1 AND @c <> '-' SELECT @r   = @r + @c;

        SELECT @x  = @x + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @r;
END;
```

Comment: Why return `varchar(MAX)`, if you can only return a string equal or smaller than the input, which is `varchar(100)`? `ISNUMERIC()` Is a poor function to check if a character is an integer, it doesn't do what most people expect it to do

Comment: Can you expound on the drawbacks of ISNUMERIC? How does it not do what is expected? This is news to me.

Comment: see for example [Is It Time To Stop Using IsNumeric()?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/)